# How to get selected objects in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I get properly selected object in TreeListView when reading SelectedObjects, however it fails when items are selected with shift key. In this case I get empty lists for SelectedObjects and SelectedIndices and SelectedIndex returns -1.

Display is showing proper selection.

I've tried traversing through all objects in tree and checking with IsSelected, but I get empty list as well.

Once I add with ctrl click some extra item I get proper selection again.

How can I get proper selection in this case? How can I disable shift selects otherwise?

Using ObjectListView 2.8.1

Comment: It works for me using SHIFT selection. I hooked up the `treeListView_SelectionChanged` event and wrote `treeListView.SelectedObjects` information to the console. It properly hold parent and child objects that are selected with SHIFT+left cick.

Comment: I tested with 2.7 and 2.8.1. Maybe its some setting...

Comment: I've tested it with demo project where I've just added handler for SelectedIndexChanged and I get empty list for SelectedObject with Shift key.Unless it's a wrong event (SelectionChanged), let me check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

As Rev1.0 has pointed out it was an issue with wrong event handler. Responding to `SelectionChanged` gives proper results. I didn't find it in documentation though.

The reason for using `SelectedIndexChanged` over `SelectionChanged` was that in my case form is hosted by another application, which does not raise `Application.Idle` event. This however can be easily fixed with `CanUseApplicationIdle` property. That's a great control.